# Statistical methods?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset, standard-deviation, accuracy

I have data from my experiment where two groups participated (monolinguals vs. bilinguals).

There was a language switching as well as a task switching part to the experiment where the data tells how fast the participants responded as well as whether or not their answer was correct (correct vs. incorrect).

Do you know good statistical methods for analyzing the data? I am trying to see whether bilinguals perform better in task switching than monolinguals.

I have looked at methods including: Two-way repeated measures ANOVA, IRT and some others but I don't feel like they apply to my case and I am therefore seeking inspiration.

Comment: Welcome Tina. You might want to edit your title to make it more specific and increase the chances of people clicking through to your question. In terms of method, is there any good reasons why a t-test would not be appropriate? Or if you want to include covariates and control for individual heterogeneity, a regression model with random intercept for individuals' ids (it could be a linear model for time to answer and a logit model for whether the answer was correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go with a t-test to compare the mean time to answer between monolinguals and bilinguals. That is all.